# setup for a small office - active directory + office 365?

Tags: windows, active-directory, microsoft-office-365

I have a small office with 4 workstations (windows with local accounts) and a NAS storage.
What is the best way to connect all computers together so anyone can login on other's computers and have access to his personal data (documents, outlook, calendar)? 
And if someone changes password on his station it should be updated on all stations.
I think I'm looking for Active Directory + office 365 but i'm not entirely sure.
Will I need a separate server for it?

Answer (score 2):

You’re too small to do Active Directory correctly on-prem.

Assuming your workstations are Windows 10, you can use Azure AD Join to join the PCs directly to the Azure AD cloud service that is powering your Office 365 environment. You will have common identities that can be used across all joined devices and can opt into using Intune for management at a later date when you grow to a large enough size.

This will *not* give you seamless access to your NAS, so you will need to maintain separate accounts local to the NAS, or move all of the NAS data into Office 365 via OneDrive, SharePoint, Office 365 Groups, or a combination of them.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much - no need for any local server, though the NAS better integrates with AD on Azure when you want those logins to work there, too.

All the heavy stuff (email server - exchange is nice, but it scales terribly to the low end) is done by Office 365 online.

Comment: Thx Tom, I will check your suggestion which seems to be right to me (I  want to avoid having any local server).

Comment: Hey Tom. Would it be difficult to the the setup which you suggested with Azure Ad + office 365? I'm a from IT background (software developer) but don't have big experience with servers. Do you think it would take few hours or few days?

Comment: No idea. While I use both Azure AD as well as Office 365 and while I am from a small company (3 people at the moment) we share around - hm -  30 servers between us on premises.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a local ActiveDirectory, as you said, with users, passwords, shares, group policys and roaming folders. AzureAD can't do that (maybe it will). So everyone can login everywhere and his/hers desktop is just there - realtime, works offline and everything is under your control. Bonus: it manages your local network (DHCP, DNS, AV ...), too. Then, get some office 365 plans for exchange, sharepoint and all the nice office stuff.

For you local server, a small "Starter" machine will do the job just fine. Grab a solid i5/4gb/SSD box and install server 2016 on it.

Comment: "AzureAD can't do that (maybe it will)." Azure AD can do that for some time now.  With Azure AD Join for Windows 10, you can use Azure AD for logon authentication and conditional access as well as automatic enrollment into Intune for policy management. Pros and Cons at http://techgenix.com/pros-and-cons-azure-ad-join/

Comment: Yes, you are right - but no roaming profiles for you and only if you are willing to pay for Intune (which is fine if you decide to do so). So I'd recommend a $$mall server for a $$mall local setup.

Comment: Well, given that the poster uses Office 365 ANYWAY.... and $$small server is anything BUT $$small. Unless you are in IT - then the Action Pack makes it quite feasible.

Comment: @bjoster Domain controllers and roaming profiles for a 4 user office? Come on. OneDrive file sync that comes with Office 365 is a much better option for something that small. It will take more servers than end user computers to do that with redundancy.

Comment: Yes, I'd do the same, but that was what free4ride requested.